# How can I reuse part of the QtCreator source in a commercial application?

Tags: qt, licensing

Suppose I have a commercial license for Qt (say, for 4.5.2 ), is it possible to reuse part of the QtCreator (say, version 2.0) source code to develop a completely proprietary software? I read the [QtLicensing](http://qt.nokia.com/products/appdev/licensing) information, but it doesn't provide any information about QtCreator licensing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

QtCreator is licensed under the LGPL just like Qt - check the [Gitorious QtCreator source tree](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/trees/master) for details, specifically [LICENSE.LGPL](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/master/LICENSE.LGPL), [LGPL_EXCEPTION.TXT](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/master/LGPL_EXCEPTION.TXT), and the [README](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-creator/qt-creator/blobs/master/README) where the various third party libraries used by QtCreator are detailed.)

Thus you can reuse the QtCreator source code in the same conditions that apply to any other LGPL-licensed product - see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945612/#2946131) for additional details.

Comment: Thank you Mihai Limbasan

Comment: Most welcome, don't mention it.

Answer (score 1):

As klez said, the best thing to do would be to ask Nokia. However, if your commercial license is for Qt 4.5.2, I seriously doubt you can apply the same license to QtCreator 2.0, because QtCreator 2.0 is based on Qt 4.7. You will want to stick to QtCreator 1.3 with Qt 4.5.

Comment: The version numbers don't matter - QtCreator is a separate product and governed by its own license. QtCreator and Qt are related only from a technological standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Using the LGPL, you can include unmodified code from Qt Creator in a proprietary application, but if you modify any of the Qt Creator code, you must make that code (just the modified code, not your entire application) available under the LGPL.